Gitlab search for merge requests across repositories
I've been given access to Gitlab in my organisation and have been tasked with creating a way to see all the merge requests for the all the repositories that my team is currently working on to ensure that it is assigned and picked up.
Is there a way to do create this search filter or dashboard to see them all? Some are in different projects and products but I was hoping to search by team member name to find ones that have been created.
Thanks

In the list of all projects, it is possible to view the number of Merge Requests per project currently open. However this remains limited unlike the /merge_requests pages.

